# Removing unwanted parts of picture

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a group of pictures, that I want to recognize the characters.I wrote the code that recognize the numbers and characters with Neural Networks, In the picture there are some other parts like Logo and the name of Company which they're not necessary.
what approach should I use to remove these things? As the name of company is somehow are connected characters my neural Network doesn't get it correctly so I remove them in later steps.

Also there between characters there are things like dash or other symbols that needed to be removed. How can I remove those?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first segment out the characters and then you pass it on to your neural net for recognition. If you have the information of the unwanted characters beforehand (i.e. if you know that only this particular Logo and dash is going to repeat) then you can have a template of it, threshold it, and find the contours. So next time you segment out the character you can do a simple shape matching available in openCV ( cv::matchShapes) and you can reject it if it matches with your set of unwanted characters.

If you do not have prior information of the unwanted characters then you can have templates of your desirable characters (A-Z,a-z,0-9) and then simply 
classify accordingly.

To remove the characters you can adopt the following approach.

Since you will be segmenting out the characters you will know which window the character belongs to. Create a binary mask image of the same size of the image, with windows of the unwanted characters as white and using inpainting available in opencv you can remove them.

Comment: you're welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it helps.